# UnexpectedToken Error that cannot be found for the life of me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot find the unexpected token error in this function to save my life. The error specifically states that it occurs on the { just before the else if statement. Says it expected a comma, but I don't see how or why? It's gotta be something really dumb.

```
onInputBlur = (event) => {
let input = event.currentTarget,
    { styles } = this.props,
    fontSize = styles.placeholder.fontSize || 10,
    top = styles.placeholder.top || 4

if(input.id === 'zip' && input.split('').length <= 4){
  return
    this.setState(state =>({
      ...state.inputCSS,
      border: '1px solid red'
    })
} else if (input.id === 'zip' && input.split('').length ){
      return
        this.setState(state => {
          ...state.inputCSS,
          border: '1px solid green'
        })
    }

    console.log(this.state.inputCSS)
}
```

Comment: you're missing a `)` ... change `})` to `}))` in the line above the else if

Comment: also ... do not put `return` on a line by itself - often, javascript engines "helpfully" consider that to be a complete statement by itself - in if and elseif cases above, your code will return undefined - i.e. identical to `return;`

Comment: Highly suggest you use a linting tool (sublime text 3 for example has a great plugin) so you don't run into these issues and get stuck. 100% worth it, and added benefit: clean, consistent code

Comment: and, finally, in your else if code, you need to wrap the code in arrow function the same way you did in the if portion

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

Your syntax error is occurring because you're missing a closing paren on the setState call.

```
this.setState(state =>({
      ...state.inputCSS,
      border: '1px solid red'
  })) // <--- neeeds one more!
```

Second, you cannot have a new line between `return` and what you are returning. So as you have written it that setState call will never fire, it will just return undefined.

```
return this.setState(state => ({
  ...state.inputCSS,
  border: '1px solid red'
}))
```